# I have a query that works fine with the first letter of the name tag but wont work with numbers?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a wordpress query to search for the initial letter of the name tag as follows.

```
 $args = array(

    'post_type'             => 'movies',
    'orderby'               => 'title',
    'order'                 => ASC,
    'posts_per_page'        => -1               
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => TRUE,
    'substring_where'       => 'A',

);
```

And in the functions.php

```
function restrict_by_first_letter( $where, $qry ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $sub = $qry->get('substring_where');
    if (!empty($sub)) {
        $where .= $wpdb->prepare(
        " AND SUBSTRING( {$wpdb->posts}.post_title, 1, 1 ) = %s ", $sub
        );
    }
    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where' , 'restrict_by_first_letter', 1 , 2 );

?>
```

Which works great but doesn't work with numbers ?

Any input would be much apprecianed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put single quotes around '%s' in your query statement:

```
function restrict_by_first_letter( $where, $qry ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $sub = $qry->get('substring_where');
    if (!empty($sub)) {
        $where .= $wpdb->prepare(
        " AND SUBSTRING( {$wpdb->posts}.post_title, 1, 1 ) = CONVERT('%s',char) ", $sub
        );
    }
    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where' , 'restrict_by_first_letter', 1 , 2 );

?>
```

Comment: sorry ben tried your solution and didn't work ... get no content found. But I know I have I'm my DB.

Comment: @scottiescotsman I erred. Put the single quotes around '%s', not $sub.

Comment: sorry for the late reply as was unwell... works great apart from 0.

Comment: @scottiescotsman Please explain what you mean by "apart from 0". There may be a simple solution.

Comment: What I mean is by the number 0 1-9 works great but 0 lists all the posts, so is in need of fixing thanks

Comment: @scottiescotsman This likely has to do with the way MySQL casts strings that are integers. Using a CONVERT statement will likely solve the problem. I've made the change in the code above.

Comment: still lists all posts if I select 0 :(

Comment: @scottiescotsman Ugh… It’s very difficult to diagnose something like this without getting to interact directly with your database engine, data, etc. One workaround is to change “if (!empty($sub)) {“ to “if ( !empty( $sub ) AND ( ( $sub === 0 ) === FALSE ) AND ( $sub <> '0' ) ) {“. This will at least cause zero to return nothing, rather than everything.